# get user profile picture form google appengine api

Tags: java, html, jsp, google-app-engine

I am using this url https://plus.google.com/s2/photos/profile/(user_id)?sz=150 
to get the current connected user profile picture in an Google app-engine application but that is not working Here is a sample of my code 
 **my problem is the line between two stars**

```
 <span class="pull-right">
    <% if (userService.getCurrentUser() == null) { %>
    <p><a href="<%= userService.createLoginURL("/help") %>">Sign in</a></p>
    <% }
    else { %>
    <p><%= userService.getCurrentUser().getNickname() %>&nbsp;
    **<img alt="user profile" src="https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/<%= userService.getCurrentUser().getUserId() %>?sz=10">**
    <a href="<%= userService.createLogoutURL("/home") %>">Sign out</a></p>

    <% } %>
    </span>
```

Please I need the correct way to do it or any suggestion thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whats not working?

If you want to get a users picture and other details you should look into the Profiles API

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/profiles/?csw=1#photo_management